# Parse Push Notification in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to implement iOS Push-Notifications using the Parse.com SDK. 
The problem is, that sometimes the Push Notification is not being sent without any error log. I have changed the code to this:

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {
    PFQuery *usernameQuery = [PFUser query];
    [usernameQuery whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:self.recipients];

    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:usernameQuery];

    PFPush *push =[[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setQuery:pushQuery];
    [push setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [PFUser currentUser].username, self.kwik]];
    [push sendPushInBackground];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSLog(@"%p", push);
}
```

I don't know if this problem is still happening with the PFPush being allocated everytime the user is sending a push.
Before I have changed the code to this one, I was calling `self.push = [[PFPush alloc] init];` in the viewDidLoad method, because I didn't like to allocate a new PFPush everytime the user is sending a Push-Notification because of memory usage.
My question now is: Is it important to allocate a new PFPush object everytime the user sends a push or can I allocate it in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: in an ARC project, which yours probably is, things allocated and not retained by something else (like a strong instance variable or placed in a collection that itself is retained) will be freed as soon as they are out of scope.  You should have no worry about the push allocated in the OP.  It lasts as long as it takes to push.

Comment: Thanks @danh, that really helped me. Unfortunately I can't mark your comment as the best answer.

Comment: glad to help.  i didn't make it an answer because the memory management advice was only half an answer if you're also experiencing issues pushing.  tried to address both in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
PFPush *push =[[PFPush alloc] init];
```

creates an object, but references to it are short-lived (the time it takes to complete the asynch push request), and in an ARC project, code will be inserted at compile time to free it, so there's no need to worry about memory allocation.

You may have an unrelated problem getting the push to send.  One way to debug is to use the [block variety of push in background called sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFPush.html#//api/name/sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:).  With that you can check the error if there is on.

Comment: This is the error log, I have logged and returned Array and a given error userInfo:  Error userInfo: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.";
    code = 119;
    error = "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.";
    originalError = "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)\"";
    temporary = 0;
}
2015-07-21 20:32:24.296 TestApplication[1411:46433] (null). But 10/10 pushes were still sent before.

Comment: Okay.  I guess that makes sense.  I had done something like the foregoing in cloud code, where you can skate around (reasonable) security constraints like that with useMasterKey.  I'll edit to remove that part of the advice.  At least the error checking in the send method can remain useful.

Comment: Yeah I also thought that this is going to be the error-output since I have read a bit about this. But one more question: is the same functionality I have written here (user to user push-notification) possible in cloud-code?

Comment: definitely.  the push you start from the clients gets done starting from parse's side of the connection to APN.